# Generate new column based on values in another column and their index

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, lookup

In the df underneath, I want to sort the values of column 'cdf_X' based on column 'A' and 'X'. Column 'X' and 'cdf_X' are connected, so if a value in 'X' appears in column 'A', the value of 'cdf_X' should be repositioned to that index number of column 'A' in a new column. (Values don't occur twice in a column 'cdf_A'.)

Example: 'X'=3 at index 0 -> cdf_X=0.05 at index 0 -> '3' appears in column 'A' at index 4 -> cdf_A at index 4 = cdf_X at index 0

Initial df:

```
    A   X   cdf_X
0   7   3    0.05
1   4   4    0.15
2  11   7    0.27
3   9   9    0.45
4   3  11    0.69
5  13  13    1.00
```

Desired df:

```
    A   X   cdf_X   cdf_A      
0   7   3    0.05    0.27     
1   4   4    0.15    0.15
2  11   7    0.27    0.69
3   9   9    0.45    0.45
4   3  11    0.69    0.05
5  13  13    1.00    1.00
```

Tried code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [7,4,11,9,3,13], 
               "cdf_X": [0.05,0.15,0.27,0.45,0.69,1.00], 
                   "X": [3,4,7,9,11,13]})

df.loc[:, 'cdf_A'] = df['cdf_X'].where(df['A'] == df['X'])
 print(df)
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  Any tutorial on data frames will teach you how to make new columns.  Most of them will also teach you how to include the row `loc` when needed.

Comment: True, true, I'm trying. The problem is not that I don't know how to make a new column df['cdf_A'] =. I just honestly don't yet know how to start. I searched for some lookup questions elsewhere but did not find anything similar yet. The explanation is clear I think, the question above can be formulated better, true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `replace`

```
df['cdf_A'] = df.A.replace(df.set_index('X').cdf)

Out[989]:
    A   X   cdf  cdf_A
0   7   3  0.05   0.27
1   4   4  0.15   0.15
2  11   7  0.27   0.69
3   9   9  0.45   0.45
4   3  11  0.69   0.05
5  13  13  1.00   1.00
```

Comment: i think use map will be safe ~, if not match will have NaN flags ~

Comment: @BEN_YO: yeah, I first thought about `map`. However, his wording seems to me he want to keep value of `A` if not found. That is the reason I changed to `replace` :)

Comment: Thanks, this works! Not sure why the map would be safer?

Comment: @Matthi9000: the difference is if value of `A` not exist in `X`, `map` returns `NaN` while `replace` keeps `A` value. If ervery `A` exists in `X`, then they are both the same.

Answer (score 3):

Check with `map`

```
df['cdf_A'] = df.A.map(df.set_index('X')['cdf'])
```